# mysql 2 table, get result from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables

1 table = files

```
      code                     | title
```

luLidwhSl8hmN0T6RsLaDmxAB09UZcX    |This is Rar title

4Xwvm1C3yTQJK7CnmxorUDI7sNSvcBK    |This is JPG title

...

2 table = hits

```
      page_name                                | hits
```

download.php?code=luLidwhSl8hmN0T6RsLaDmxAB09UZcX    |102

download.php?code=4Xwvm1C3yTQJK7CnmxorUDI7sNSvcBK    |87

...

My Query is :

```
            include('db.inc.php');
            $query = mysql_query("SELECT t1.code, t1.title, RIGHT(t2.page_name, 31) as t2.page_name, t2.hits FROM files t1 INNER JOIN hits t2 ON t1.code= RIGHT(t2.page_name, 31) as t2.page_name ORDER by t2.hits DESC LIMIT 1, 7");

            while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
                echo ' <div id="linkstyle"><strong><a href="http://localhost/edu/filesupload/download.php?code='. $result['t1.code'] . ' ">' , $result['t1.title'] , '</a></strong><br></div>';
                }
```

I get this error

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Edu\filesupload\index.php on line 104
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT t1.code, t1.title, RIGHT(t2.page_name, 31) as t2.page_name, t2.hits FROM files t1 INNER JOIN hits t2 ON t1.code= RIGHT(t2.page_name, 31) as t2.page_name ORDER by t2.hits DESC LIMIT 1, 7");`

To this:

`$query = mysql_query("SELECT t1.code, t1.title, RIGHT(t2.page_name, 31) as t2.page_name, t2.hits FROM files t1 INNER JOIN hits t2 ON t1.code= RIGHT(t2.page_name, 31) as t2.page_name ORDER by t2.hits DESC LIMIT 1, 7") or die(mysql_error());`

Then that should tell you what the error is, because if it was fine, it wouldn't be returning false.

Comment: My error is :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.page_name, t2.hits FROM files t1 INNER JOIN hits t2 ON t1.code= RIGHT(t2.page_n' at line 1

Comment: That is the answer :$query = mysql_query("SELECT t1.code, t1.title, RIGHT(t2.page_name, 31), t2.hits FROM files t1 INNER JOIN hits t2 ON t1.code = RIGHT(t2.page_name, 31) ORDER by t2.hits DESC LIMIT 1, 7");

Answer (score 1):

Try with this query:

```
SELECT t1.code, t1.title, RIGHT(t2.page_name, 31) as page_name, t2.hits FROM files t1 INNER JOIN hits t2 ON t1.code= RIGHT(t2.page_name, 31) ORDER by t2.hits DESC LIMIT 1, 7
```

Comment: Some error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.page_name, t2.hits FROM files t1 INNER JOIN hits t2 ON t1.code= RIGHT(t2.page_n' at line 1